# Power BI: Invert Primary Y-Axis, but not Secondary Y-Axis

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I have a chart with a primary and secondary y-axis. I would like the primary axis to be inverted, but the secondary one to remain normal. From what I've researched so far, this doesn't look to be a possibility. As a workaround, I've created a DAX measure so that the field on the secondary axis is multiplied by -1.

My 2 questions are:

1. Is there a way to invert the primary Y-Axis, but not the secondary?
2. Can the measure I created as a workaround be manipulated so that even though it is a negative number, the secondary axis labels (and data labels) still show positive values?